# Kotlinx Serialization

Tags: android, kotlin, serialization

i am trying to migrate to Kotlinx Serialization and i am running into an issue

here's the structure of the data class in question

```
@Serializable
sealed class X {
abstract val type: String

@Serializable
@SerialName("X")
data class Y(
@SerialName("a") val a: String,
@SerialName("b") val b: String
) : X() {
    @SerialName("type") override val myType: String
}
```

the issue i'm having is that since i am overriding the type i had to use

```
useArrayPolymorphism = true
```

and doing that now results in sending the request with the below Json

```
"X" : [
   "X": {
     "type": "type here",
     "a": "value here",
     "b": "value here"
   }
]
```

when it should be just

```
   "X": {
     "type": "type here",
     "a": "value here",
     "b": "value here"
   }
```